# $http.get to SharePoint Online failing from Outlook Add-in

Tags: angularjs, office365, sharepoint-online, outlook-web-addins

I am writing an Outlook Add-In (for Office 365) using AngularJs (v. 1.3.15) that is using $http.get to call the SharePoint Online search API. I have abstracted my search calls into an Angular factory which I call from the primary controller.

The issue is that the $http.get call never calls the callback success or error functions. If I trace it in IE, I don't even see the request to SharePoint Online go over the wire.

Using very similar code in a stand alone Angular SPA, it works just fine. Here is some pseudo code to illustrate what I am doing...

App Controller

```
searchFactory.search(terms).then(function(response){
    $scope.results = response.data;
},
function(error){
    $scope.status = "Error";
});
```

Search factory:

```
factory.search = function(terms){
    var queryStr = buildQueryStr(terms);    
    var results = $http.get(queryStr);
    return results;
}
```

The factory code executes but I never see the request to the search endpoint go over the wire and neither the success nor the error function in the call in the controller is triggered.

The only error in the JavaScript console is something about no conversationId, but that doesn't seem relevant given that I'm calling the SPO API. Worth noting that the call is X-domain.

I am totally stumped. Any pointers are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

According to dev.office.com, cross-domain requests are blocked by Outlook Web due to same-origin policy:

http://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/develop/addressing-same-origin-policy-limitations

I believe the SharePoint online API supports CORS so you can use that to get around the policy.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/create-web-apps-using-cors-to-access-files-in-office-365